# PictureBox Drawed image colors to array

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, drawing, picturebox

I got 400x300 picturebox, which got an "mousedown" event, which puts some red filled Ellipses in place of mouseclick. The problem i got now, i want to get colors of every single pixel into an array. I got only 3 colors there, black (0,0,0 in RGB), red(255,0,0) and while(255,255,255).
The question is, how can i run trough whole picturebox and TAKE colors values? There is no "getPixel" i could use. I tried passing the image of pictureBox to bitmap

```
Bitmap zdjecie_box = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image)
```

but it says image properly is empty (null), so i guess drawed image isnt stored in .image, but somewhere else. I wanted that, cuz then i would just use `zdjecie_box.GetPixel(i, j).R;` and save it to array.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your own image and set that on the draw event, you can easily access it. e.g.

```
 Bitmap _b;
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
    _b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_b);
    g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black,new Rectangle(0,0,25,25));
    pictureBox1.Image = _b;
 }
 ...
 private void ParseImage()
 {
    for (int y = 0; y < _b.Height; y++)
    {
       for (int x = 0; x < _b.Width; x++)
       {
          Color c = _b.GetPixel(x, y);
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I guess i love you now. Thank you :)